# Montrer de quel bois on se chauffe: origine et rapport avec la qualité d'une personne

Tags: étymologie, origine-ou-raison, proverbes

Bonjour,

Concernant l'expression « montrer de quel bois je me chauffe » :

1. Quel est le rapport entre le bois dont on se chauffe et la qualité d'une personne ? Par exemple, pourquoi pas « de quel bois je suis fait » au lieu de « je me chauffe ».
2. D'où vient l'expression étymologiquement ?

Merci d'avance.
LQ

Comment: _Réchauffe_? Je ne connais l'expression qu'avec _chauffe_: _de quel bois je me chauffe_.

Comment: _Si tous les fols portoient marotte on ne sçait de quel bois on se chaufferoit._ ;-)

Answer (score 2):

*1. Quel est le rapport entre le bois dont on se chauffe et la qualité d'une personne ?*

L'expression est ancienne. Nul doute que plus le rang d'une personne était élevé, plus elle avait une grande cheminée et les moyens de brûler des bois nobles, secs et imposants alors qu'en bas de l'échelle, du bois de moindre qualité, du « tout-venant » devait être plus souvent utilisé.

*2. Par exemple, pourquoi pas « de quel bois je suis fait » au lieu de « je me chauffe ».*

Être fait de bois n'est pas une expression qu'on associe forcément à la qualité.

*3. D'où vient l'expression étymologiquement ?*

Comme déjà indiqué en [commentaire](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/54080/montrer-de-quel-bois-on-se-chauffe-origine-et-rapport-avec-la-qualit%C3%A9-dune-per#comment115299_54080), Cotgrave rapporte cette expression dès le XVI<sup>e</sup> siècle:

> *Si tous les fols portoient marotte, on ne sçait pas de quel bois on se chaufferoit*

Ici, c'est bien à la qualité des personnes (précisément à leur santé mentale dans ce cas) que l'expression fait référence.

Furetière écrit en 1690:

> *On dit en menaçant, Il verra de quel bois je me chauffe, pour dire, Je le bastonneray du bois que j'ay à mon feu.*

Quand la première personne est utilisée, la phrase exprime une menace.